# TypeORM: How to handle optional querying over relation id

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have a service for retrieving user application's, one that accepts optional parameter `listingId` (that's an application's relation) and has a fixed WHERE clause for `user.id` being equal to one from the incoming authenticated request:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: any) {}

  async list(listingId?: string) {
    return Application.find({
      where: {
        user: { id: this.request.user.id },
        listing: { id: listingId }
      },
    })
  }
}
```

unfortunately implementation above returns an empty array. Probably because `{ listing: { id: undefined } }` results in a "IS NULL" query, correct?. I found a workaround for that:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: any) {}

  async list(listingId?: string) {
    return Application.find({
      where: {
        user: { id: this.request.user.id },
        ...(listingId && { listing: { id: listingId } }),
      },
    })
  }
}
```

but I'm looking for a more generic/nicer way since in the future I can have more than one optional parameter and having to spread them like this is ugly and error prone. Not to mention that the code is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

A service? But what framework are you using? NestJS? It sorta looks like it but isn't very idiomatic.

I would propose using the TypeORM QueryBuilder instead for more complex queries, especially one with lots of conditionals.

Refer to the docs at:

https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder

You can split things up for code readability.

For example, start with a `const query = [...].createQueryBuilder('example')`
and then you can conditionally add clauses to your `query` with the various available methods (e.g. `addSelect()`, `.where()`, `andWhere()`, `.innerJoin()`, etc, etc) before concluding with a `.getOne()`, `.getRawOne()`, `.getMany()`, `.getRawMany()`.

Re TypeORM be careful about assuming how it handles `undefined`. Check out `Not`, `IsNull`, etc from the typeorm package if you wish to be explicit in a `find()` query.

Comment: It's NestJS. Why isn't it idiomatic?